# Pandas faster apply pd.pct_change for multiple columns and multiple intervals

Tags: python, pandas, loops, apply, multi-index

I am looping through a multiindex'd Pandas dataframe to generate historical percentage change columns for each column. The first level of the index is the date. The second level of the index is the symbol. The head of the input data is:

```
                   price_open  price_high  price_low  price_close  volume  price_adj_close
date       symbol                                                                         
1962-01-02 AA           65.37       65.75      65.37        65.37  134400             0.70
1962-01-03 AA           65.37       66.37      65.25        66.37  179200             0.71
1962-01-04 AA           66.37       66.87      66.37        66.37  193600             0.71
1962-01-05 AA           66.37       66.75      66.12        66.25  169600             0.71
1962-01-08 AA           66.00       66.00      63.50        64.00  225600             0.68
```

The ideal output should have a series of columns for each input column. My output dataframe is rather wide, but here's a list of the column names for the full dataframe:

> Index(['price_open', 'price_high', 'price_low', 'price_close',
>   'volume', 'price_adj_close', 'price_open_1d_pct', 'price_open_3d_pct',
>   'price_open_5d_pct', 'price_open_10d_pct', 'price_open_15d_pct',
>   'price_open_30d_pct', 'price_high_1d_pct', 'price_high_3d_pct',
>   'price_high_5d_pct', 'price_high_10d_pct', 'price_high_15d_pct',
>   'price_high_30d_pct', 'price_low_1d_pct', 'price_low_3d_pct',
>   'price_low_5d_pct', 'price_low_10d_pct', 'price_low_15d_pct',
>   'price_low_30d_pct', 'price_close_1d_pct', 'price_close_3d_pct',
>   'price_close_5d_pct', 'price_close_10d_pct', 'price_close_15d_pct',
>   'price_close_30d_pct', 'volume_1d_pct', 'volume_3d_pct',
>   'volume_5d_pct', 'volume_10d_pct', 'volume_15d_pct', 'volume_30d_pct',
>   'price_adj_close_1d_pct', 'price_adj_close_3d_pct',
>   'price_adj_close_5d_pct', 'price_adj_close_10d_pct',
>   'price_adj_close_15d_pct', 'price_adj_close_30d_pct',
>   'price_7d_future'], dtype='object')

Here is the head of the output dataframe:

```
                  price_open  price_high  price_low  price_close  volume  price_adj_close  price_open_1d_pct  price_open_3d_pct  price_open_5d_pct  price_open_10d_pct  price_open_15d_pct  price_open_30d_pct  price_high_1d_pct  price_high_3d_pct  price_high_5d_pct  price_high_10d_pct  price_high_15d_pct  price_high_30d_pct  price_low_1d_pct  price_low_3d_pct  price_low_5d_pct  price_low_10d_pct  price_low_15d_pct  price_low_30d_pct  price_close_1d_pct  price_close_3d_pct  price_close_5d_pct  price_close_10d_pct  price_close_15d_pct  price_close_30d_pct  volume_1d_pct  volume_3d_pct  volume_5d_pct  volume_10d_pct  volume_15d_pct  volume_30d_pct  price_adj_close_1d_pct  price_adj_close_3d_pct  price_adj_close_5d_pct  price_adj_close_10d_pct  price_adj_close_15d_pct  price_adj_close_30d_pct  price_7d_future
date       symbol                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
1962-02-13 AA           58.75       59.13      58.75        58.88  150400             0.63           0.008584          -0.006427          -0.006427           -0.010610           -0.028926           -0.101270           0.012847          -0.004210           0.000000           -0.012525           -0.032717           -0.100684          0.010666          0.004274          0.008584          -0.010610          -0.022950          -0.101270            0.012902            0.000000            0.002213            -0.016700            -0.020788            -0.099281       2.760000       0.205128       0.540984        1.043478        0.807692        0.119048                0.016129                0.000000                0.000000                -0.015625                -0.015625                -0.100000         0.031746
1962-02-14 AA           58.50       58.50      57.63        58.00  136000             0.62          -0.004255          -0.006454          -0.006454           -0.023046           -0.027108           -0.105094          -0.010654          -0.012658          -0.016807           -0.025000           -0.027108           -0.118578         -0.019064         -0.010644         -0.021230          -0.033540          -0.014872          -0.116782           -0.014946           -0.004292           -0.019110            -0.029289            -0.029289            -0.126111      -0.095745       0.666667       0.231884        0.011905        0.231884       -0.241071               -0.015873                0.000000               -0.015873                -0.031250                -0.031250                -0.126761         0.048387
1962-02-15 AA           58.00       59.00      57.50        57.50  150400             0.62          -0.008547          -0.004292          -0.019110           -0.027335           -0.029289           -0.126111           0.008547           0.010620          -0.006399           -0.010565           -0.014696           -0.117691         -0.002256         -0.010838         -0.017094          -0.021277          -0.027566          -0.133645           -0.008621           -0.010838           -0.023438            -0.031660            -0.027566            -0.133645       0.105882       2.760000       0.205128       -0.078431        0.649123       -0.223140                0.000000                0.000000               -0.015873                -0.015873                -0.015873                -0.126761         0.048387
1962-02-16 AA           57.50       58.38      57.50        58.38  134400             0.62          -0.008621          -0.021277          -0.023438           -0.031660           -0.027566           -0.133645          -0.010508          -0.012684          -0.014684           -0.022929           -0.016841           -0.125393          0.000000         -0.021277         -0.012876          -0.025424          -0.027566          -0.130369            0.015304           -0.008492            0.002232            -0.012684            -0.016841            -0.118792      -0.106383      -0.106383       0.647059        0.826087        0.473684       -0.207547                0.000000               -0.015873                0.000000                -0.015873                -0.015873                -0.126761         0.048387
1962-02-19 AA           58.50       59.00      58.50        58.88   72000             0.63           0.017391           0.000000           0.004292           -0.016807           -0.014820           -0.113636           0.010620           0.008547           0.010620           -0.014696           -0.012552           -0.106061          0.017391          0.015096          0.006365          -0.016807          -0.010654          -0.078740            0.008565            0.015172            0.012902            -0.010420            -0.006245            -0.080000      -0.464286      -0.470588       0.800000       -0.587156       -0.296875       -0.680851                0.016129                0.016129                0.016129                 0.000000                 0.000000                -0.073529         0.063492
```

This code as follows runs quite slow because there are millions of records and I can't quite figure out how to quicken it up. Can anyone provide some coding tips to speed up this code?

```
 features_targets_df = pd.DataFrame()
 for s in df.index.unique(level='symbol'):
    stock_df = df.iloc[df.index.get_level_values('symbol') == s].copy()

    for c in stock_df:
        for n in [1, 3, 5, 10, 15, 30]:  # make day-change columns
            stock_df['{}_{}d_pct'.format(c, str(n))] = stock_df[c].pct_change(n)  

    stock_df = stock_df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)

    stock_df['price_7d_future'] = stock_df['price_adj_close'].shift(-7).pct_change(7)

    features_targets_df = features_targets_df.append(stock_df)
```

Comment: Please post `code-formatted` data instead of an image so that we can copy it directly. Also, please provide your expected output.

Comment: Edited the posting per your suggestion and a bunch of other things

Comment: In your code you have `stock_name_column`. Can I assume this is the same as the index level `symbol` in your input data?

Comment: And which column are you referring to with `stock_price_column`? `target_time_prediction`? The code is appreciated, but it would be nicer if it was executable.

Comment: Apololgies, I took out the stock_name_column and target_time_prediction variables now (and some others).

Answer (score 2):

When I originally tried to speed this up I used your data, but 5 rows wasn't enough to support actual evidence. So I created a much larger data frame (1k rows) with 2 symbols using the same format you already have. Here is the code to replicate my test data:

```
import pandas as pd # version 0.23.4
import numpy as np # version 1.15.4

np.random.seed(1)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=[
    pd.date_range(start='1962-01-02', periods=1000, freq='D'),
    ['AA']*500 + ['BB']*500
], columns=[
    'price_open',
    'price_high',
    'price_low',
    'price_close',
    'volume',
    'price_adj_close'
], data=np.random.random(size=(1000, 6)))

df1.index.names = ['date', 'symbol']
```

I timed your original code using this new data:

```
%%timeit

features_targets_df = pd.DataFrame()
for s in df1.index.unique(level='symbol'):
    stock_df = df1.iloc[df.index.get_level_values('symbol') == s].copy()

    for c in stock_df:
        for n in [1, 3, 5, 10, 15, 30]:  # make day-change columns
            stock_df['{}_{}d_pct'.format(c, str(n))] = stock_df[c].pct_change(n)

    stock_df = stock_df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)

    stock_df['price_7d_future'] = stock_df['price_adj_close'].shift(-2).pct_change(2)

    features_targets_df = features_targets_df.append(stock_df)
```

Output

```
159 ms ± 23.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

My code replaces some of the `for-loops` with `groupby()` and `apply()`:

```
%%timeit

# copy original df instead of defining empty one
features_targets_df = df1.copy()

# loop through the day changes
for n in [1, 3, 5, 10, 15, 30]:
    # groupby the "symbol" index level
    # focus on the necessary columns (otherwise the second + loops will calculate pct_change across all new columns)
    # apply pct_change to each series using lambda
    # add suffix to the new columns (I used f-strings because I'm using Python 3.7.1, but these became available in 3.6)
    # replace +/- infinity with nan
    # join to features_targets_df
    features_targets_df = features_targets_df.join(features_targets_df.groupby(level='symbol')[
        [
            'price_open',
            'price_high',
            'price_low',
            'price_close',
            'volume',
            'price_adj_close'
        ]
    ].apply(lambda x : x.pct_change(n)).add_suffix(f"_{n}d_pct")).replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)

# groupby "symbol" index level and calculate 7d future
features_targets_df['price_7d_future'] = features_targets_df.groupby(level='symbol').price_adj_close.shift(-2).pct_change(2)
```

Output

```
88.4 ms ± 22.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Cuts the time down by almost 50%. Hopefully this helps some!